# What will be the primary OS

Tags: windows

I was just wondering, if I download Ubuntu to my laptop which has a windows 8 as its OS, will I be able to use either Ubuntu or Windows as its OS?

Or will Ubuntu be the primary OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

You will be provided with a OS selection menu ,the `Grub2` menu from which you can select the OS to which you want to boot into.Ubuntu will be the default OS  but it can be changed to  Windows if you like it that way.

Check out the following image of Grub2 (Ubuntu + Windows XP)

[image]

More [info on GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu along side Windows 8, you will be offered a choice when ever you start up. The 'GRUB' menu will offer you a choice of  what ever operating system is on your computer.

**IMPORTANT**

Windows 8 and Ubuntu, visit this page first [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)